# How to do CRUD operations for locally saved JSON in react js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**fetch the json from any endpoint and save it locally**

```
fetch("any endpoint")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {

  this.state ={
       data:responseJson 
      }

})
```

**How to do CRUD to change for locally sample json**

```
{ "key": "value" }
```

**to add new key for to delete key and value and to update **

Answer (score 1):

For adding/updating a `state` use `setState`.

```
this.setState({
   data:responseJson 
})
```

For removing a `state` just set the `data` to `undefined` as shown below

```
this.setState({
  data: undefined
})
```

For reading `data`,

```
console.log(this.state.data);
```

Comment: no my question is how to do crud to add new like if you click a button to add new data it has to do this.setState({key : new key , value : new value}) it has to be added to local data for update i have to take key and to update particular key value